# AttributeError: module 'signal' has no attribute 'SIGINT'

Tags: python, sigint

I am encountering the following error:

```
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\joblib\externals\loky\backend\resource_tracker.py", line 66, in <module>
    _IGNORED_SIGNALS = (signal.SIGINT, signal.SIGTERM)
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'signal' has no attribute 'SIGINT'
```

I tried upgrading `joblib` but it did not work.

Comment: Part of [python itself](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#signal.SIGINT). Do you have module or script called `signal` which cause import conflicts?

Comment: @ivvija yes i noticed this was what the error came from , thank youu